# Convert v1 .Net Activity to v2 Custom Activity c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

How to convert the below code(v1) to azure data factory custom activity v2?

```
public IDictionary<string, string> Execute(
    IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices,
    IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets,
    Activity activity,
    IActivityLogger logger)
{
//Code here
}
```

Can we replace `IDictionary` with main ?

Appreciate any help

Comment: what return type do you require?

Comment: Did you check this doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity#compare-v2-v1